# unbound variables in monad associativity law

Tags: haskell, closures, monads, associativity

Using `ghci` I have computed:

```
Prelude> let m = [1,2]
Prelude> let ys = [4, 5, 6]
Prelude> m >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))
[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6)]
```

The monadic expression above doesn't seem to correspond to either side of the monad associativity law:

```
(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)
```

I would like to know how monad associativity can be applied to the expression:

```
m >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))
```

Because `return (x,y)` closes on both the surrounding function and the one containing it, it seems that an intermediate monad, as exists on the left side of the associativity law `(m >>= f)`, cannot exist in this example.

Comment: I don't quite see the right hand side of the associativity law in your function. `ys` isn't consuming the bound `x`, i.e. your function is not in monadic normal form.

Comment: @shelf i think it comes down to the fact that: `\x -> x` is a function, but `\x -> (x,y)` isn't.  For example, 

`[1,2] >>= (\x -> [x, x+1] >>= (\y -> [y+20,y-20]))` gives `[21,-19,22,-18,22,-18,23,-17]` and (respecting the associative law)
`[1,2] >>= (\x -> [x, x+1]) >>= (\y -> [y+20,y-20])` gives `[21,-19,22,-18,22,-18,23,-17]` However, while  
`[1,2] >>= (\x -> [x, x+1] >>= (\y -> [x+y+20,y-20]))` gives `[22,-19,23,-18,24,-18,25,-17]`, this
`[1,2] >>= (\x -> [x, x+1]) >>= (\y -> [x+y+20,y-20])` raises an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it's not possible to directly apply the associative law, because of the scope of `x` in the original expression:

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)

test = let m = [1,2]
           ys = [4, 5, 6]
       in m >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))
```

However, we can reduce the scope of `x` if we include it into the result of the first monadic computation. Instead of returning `[Int]` in `x -> ys`, we'll use `\x -> liftM ((,) x) ys` and return `[(Int,Int)]`, where the first number in each pair is always `x` and the second is one of `ys`. (Note that for lists `liftM` is the same as `map`.) And the second function will read the value of `x` from its input:

```
test1 = let m = [1,2]
            ys = [4, 5, 6]
        in m >>= (\x -> liftM ((,) x) ys >>= (\(x', y) -> return (x', y)))
```

(The monadic function `\(x', y) -> return (x', y)` could be now simplified just to `return`, and subsequently `>>= return` removed completely, but let's keep it there for the sake of the argument.)

Now each monadic function is self-contained and we can apply the associativity law:

```
test2 = let m = [1,2]
            ys = [4, 5, 6]
        in (m >>= \x -> liftM ((,) x) ys) >>= (\(x, y) -> return (x, y))
```

Comment: Why would you use `liftM` when every monadic expression of the form `m >>= f` can be simply expanded to `(m >>= return) >>= f` to lift it to the associative monadic law form - `(m >>= f) >>= g`?

Comment: It's important to take into account what `liftM` expands to.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you're confusing the monadic laws for the structure of a monadic expression. The monadic associativity law states that the expression `(m >>= f) >>= g` must be equivalent to the expression `m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)` for the data type of `m` to be considered a monad.

**This does not imply that every monadic expression must be of the form `(m >>= f) >>= g`.**

For example `m >>= f` is a perfectly valid monadic expression even though it's not of the form `(m >>= f) >>= g`. However it still obeys the monadic associativity law because `m` can be expanded to `m >>= return` (from the monadic right identity law `m >>= return ≡ m`). Hence:

```
m >>= f

-- is equivalent to

(m >>= return) >>= f

-- is of the form

(m >>= f) >>= g
```

In your example `m >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))` is of the form `m >>= f` where `f` is `\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y))`.

Although `\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y))` is not of the form `\x -> f x >>= g` (from the right hand side of the monadic associativity law) it doesn't mean that it breaks the monadic laws.

The expression `m >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))` can be expanded into the monadic associative form by substituting `m >>= return` for `m`:

```
(m >>= return) >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y)))

-- is of the form

(m >>= f) >>= g

-- and can be written as

m >>= (\x -> return x >> (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y))))
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

The monadic law applies to functions of one arguments only. The expression

```
xs >>= (\x -> ys >>= (\y -> (x, y)))
```

is really equivalent to:

```
xs >>= \x -> fmap ($ x) $ ys >>= \y -> return (\x -> (x,y))
```

(if we were to avoid capturing `x`)

So you can't apply the same laws - we have `fmap` as `f` and no `g` from the associativity law.

The above is of course the same as:

```
xs >>= \x -> fmap ($ x) $ fmap (\y x -> (x,y)) ys
```

or

```
xs >>= \x -> fmap (\y -> (x,y)) ys
```